# Find indices of common elements in arraylists in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have several ArrayLists with no repeated elements. I want to find their intersection and return indices of common elements in each arraylist.
For example, if I have input as `{0,1,2},{3,0,4},{5,6,0}`, then I want to return `{0},{1},{2}` i.e. indices of common element 0 here.
One way I can think of is to use succesive `retainAll()` on all ArrayLists to get intersection, and then finding indices of elements of intersection using `indexOf()` for each input ArrayList.
Is there a better way to do that ?

Comment: Are you expecting only one element to be common accross your lists?

Comment: No, there can be many.

Comment: By 'better' do you mean 'more elegant' or 'more efficient'? I suspect you'll get different answers for each of these.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting the list first would require at least `O(nlogn)` time. If you are looking for a more efficient algorithm you could get `O(n)` using hashmaps.

For example with

```
A=[0,1,2],B=[3,0,4],C=[5,6,0]
```

You can loop through each list and append elements with a hash on the element. The final hash will look like

```
H = {0:[0,1,2], 1:[1], 2:[2], 3:[0], 4:[2], 5:[0], 6:[1]}
```

Here, the key is the element, and the value is the index in it's corresponding list. Now, just loop through the hashmap to find any lists that have a size of 3, in this case, to get the indices.

---

The code would look something like this (untested):

```
int[][] lists = {{0,1,2}, {3,0,4}, {5,6,0}};

// Create the hashmap
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> H = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
for(int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < lists[0].length; j++){
        // create the list if this is the first occurance
        if(!H.containsKey(lists[i][j]))
            H.put(lists[i][j], new ArrayList<Integer>());

        // add the index to the list
        H.get(lists[i][j]).add(j);
    }
}

// Print out indexes for elements that are shared between all lists
for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> e : H.entrySet()){
    // check that the list of indexes matches the # of lists
    if(e.getValue().size() == lists.length){
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue());
    }
}
```

EDIT: Just noticed you suggested using retainAll() in your question. That would also be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very inefficient but fairly readable solution using streams that returns you a list of lists.

```
int source[][];

Arrays.stream(source)
    .map(list -> IntMap.range(0, list.length)
        .filter(i -> Arrays.stream(source)
            .allMatch(l -> Arrays.binarySearch(l, list[i]) >= 0))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can add toArray calls to convert to arrays if required.